# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _reactNative.NativeModules.RNDatePickerAndroid.dismiss is not a function

Tags: react-native, expo

I just used DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker'. I getting error whenever I changed the date. I just updating the state to show to the calender to select. Error is showing whenever I change the state to false

```
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    console.log('Seleeected', selectedDate);   
      setShow(false);
   
  };

return( 
 {show && (
              <DateTimePicker
                testID="dateTimePicker"
                value={dateValue}
                mode="date"
                display="spinner"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            )}  {show && (
              <DateTimePicker
                testID="dateTimePicker"
                value={dateValue}
                mode="date"
                display="spinner"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            )}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there're some issues referenced to this on the repo itself:

- https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/issues/502#issuecomment-745833136
- https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/376
- https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/369

Which says, updating your Expo from 38 to 40.0.0 can solve the problem.

Also, if you're using expo, install it with `expo install <library_name>`

Installing Expo libraries with `yarn install` can cause some native modules problems since it may conflict with Expo SDK.

After that, rebuild your project.

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

If you are still having this issue, it looks like you just need to re-run the install for datepicker and then rebuild. Then you should be good to go.

Here's the command:
expo install @react-native-community/datetimepicker